# Trek 520 (2021) saddle dimensions

Tags: saddle, trek

Does anyone have dimensions (width) for the stock saddle that comes with a Trek 520 2021 model?  The Trek website simply describes it as "Bontrager Evoke"

Comment: In this particular case, you will find that Trek customer service is possibly the best in the bicycle industry and they *should* be able to answer this question if you call them directly. This is my experience of dealing with them in the past.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different Bontrager evoke saddles.
A quick search turns up the Evoke RL, Evoke RXL, Evoke R, Evoke 1, Evoke 1.5, Evoke 3....
It is difficult to know what changes were introduced between models or exactly which model is on the bike.

According to [trekbicyclesuperstore](https://www.trekbicyclesuperstore.com/product/bontrager-evoke-rl-factory-overstock-mountain-bike-saddle-340780-1.htm) the Evoke RL is 138mm wide

According to [sweetpetes.com](https://www.sweetpetes.com/product/bontrager-evoke-1-oem-saddle-9637.htm) the Evoke 1 OEM saddle is 138mm wide

It's been my experience that published numbers may or may not represent:

1. Reality
2. How I would have measured it
   So a grain or so of salt may be needed.

Comment: The vendors usually try to keep the shape the same but add various features and better or lighter materials in higher-end variations. Not sure it is the case here, but it is quite common.

Comment: The subject of saddle dimensions did come up on a recent Bikefit.com podcast, and I think they would agree that there’s no industry standard on how to measure saddles. The parameter given should be something like width at the widest part, but as you said, define the widest part! However, 138mm should be a relatively narrow saddle; wide versions have quoted widths in the 150s or 160s, I believe.